# What package is used in Fedora 29 to install xblacklight?

Tags: fedora, xorg

I installed Fedora 29 and do not use the wayland Gnome. I use x11 with i3. However, when I went to use xblacklight to adjust my laptop backlight, the command was not found. I also tried using it as sudo and even searched for it with find and grep. I looked online and tried to find the package and could not.

Comment: `sudo dnf whatprovides xbacklight` shows the `fedora` repo contains this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `xbacklight`, if you had a typo. What does it say, when you type `dnf install xbacklight`?

Comment: That was it, I misspelled it